# Clean up multiple timeouts from React provider

Tags: reactjs, timeout, state

I have the following React provider:

```
import { createContext, useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export const AlertContext = createContext({
  addAlert: () => {},
  alerts: [],
  clearAlert: () => {},
  setAlerts: () => {},
});

export function useAlert() {
  return useContext(AlertContext);
}

export function AlertProvider(props: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([]);

  const clearAlert = useCallback(
    (idToRemove: string | null) => {
      // Clear a specific alert by ID.
      if (idToRemove) {
        setAlerts(alerts => alerts.filter(a => a.id !== idToRemove));
        return;
      }
    },
    [],
  );

  const addAlert = useCallback(
    (alert: any, options?: { autoDismissTime?: number }) => {
      setAlerts(alerts => {
  
        if (options?.autoDismissTime) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            clearAlert(alert.id);
          }, options.autoDismissTime)
        }

        return [...alerts, alert];
      });
    },
    [clearAlert],
  );

  return (
    <AlertContext.Provider value={{ alerts, setAlerts, addAlert, clearAlert }}>
      {props.children}
      <ClientOnly>
        {() => <AlertContainer alerts={alerts} clearAlert={clearAlert} />}
      </ClientOnly>
    </AlertContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

And then in one of my components I do this:

```
const { addAlert } = useAlert();
// Add the alert
addAlert(...)
```

I would like to know what is the proper way to ensure that I don't leave any timeouts hanging in that provider (how should I manage the `clearTimeout`). I have seen examples on how to unset a specific timer in a component when it unmounts, but in this case I can have multiple timeouts (as many as alerts are being set with an `autoDismissTime`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the start of the component:

```
const timeoutsRef = useRef<Record<number, number>>([])
```

Then:

```
const id = setTimeout(() => {
  clearAlert(alert.id);
  delete timeoutsRef.current[alert.id]
}, options.autoDismissTime)
timeoutsRef.current[alert.id] = id
```

And then cleanup:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    Object.values(timeoutsRef.current).forEach((id) => {
      clearTimeout(id)
    })
  }
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks! Why this line: `delete timeoutsRef.current[alert.id]`

Comment: So the object won't get massive after time

Comment: Perfect, and lastly, would you mind explaining why do we need to have the timeouts in a ref?

Comment: I am getting this warning on the cleanup line:

```1. The ref value 'autoDismissTimeoutsRef.current' will likely have changed by the time this effect cleanup function runs. If this ref points to a node rendered by React, copy 'timeoutsRef.current' to a variable inside the effect, and use that variable in the cleanup function. [react-hooks/exhaustive-deps]
```